Hellmann-Feynman theorem and the derivation of the Lippmann-Schwinger equation
When deriving the Lippmann-Schwinger equation, one denotes
$$H_\text{free}|\phi\rangle = E|\phi\rangle \tag{1}$$
with $H_\text{free}$ as the free Hamiltonian and
$$H|\psi\rangle = E|\psi\rangle \tag{2}$$
with the total Hamiltonian $H$ containing the scattering potential $H = H_\text{free} + V$. Of course, the energy eigenvalue remains unchanged because we are dealing with elastic scattering. Then, physically, it totally makes sense for $|\psi\rangle \rightarrow |\phi\rangle$ as $V \rightarrow 0$ and this is a boundary condition for the equation.
I was searching for a rigorous proof for "$|\psi\rangle \rightarrow |\phi\rangle$ as $V \rightarrow 0$" when I stumbled into this Wikipedia article where it says that

"...the Hellmann-Feynman theorem requires the energy eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian to change continuously with continuous changes in Hamiltonian and therefore,  we wish that $|\psi\rangle \rightarrow |\phi\rangle$ as $V \rightarrow 0$...".

I do not understand the implication here. It starts with a mathematical statement of the Hellmann-Feynman theorem
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}E_\lambda}{\mathrm{d}\lambda} = \left\langle\psi_\lambda\left|\frac{\mathrm{d}H_\lambda}{\mathrm{d}\lambda}\right|\psi_\lambda\right\rangle$$
and argues by continuously changing the energy eigenvalue. But the energy eigenvalue has to remain unchanged in order for us to compare (1) and (2)...
So, besides this point of confusion, I am also asking for an explanation as to why the above-cited statement holds mathematically.
